# How to create multiple tables in sqlite for react native?

Tags: react-native, sqlite

The basic construct of creating a single table in sqlite db is as follows:

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('students.db')

export const init = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stud(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);',
        [],
        () => {
          resolve()
        },
        (_, err) => {
          reject(err)
        }
      )
    })
  })
  return promise
}
```

However how to create another table (say) teachers?

Answer (score 2):

I currently have no setup to test it but in general, this should work.

```
export const init = async () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction(async (tx) => {
      await tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stud(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);')
await tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);')
resolve();
    })
  })
  return promise
}
```